# Сгруппировать Модель SQLite

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

Пишу приложение на C# WPF типа будильник.
Будильники хранятся в базе SqLite.

Использую Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite

Подключение

```
public class AlarmContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<AlarmModel> AlarmModels { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        _ = optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source = alarm.db");
    }
}
```

Модель

```
public class AlarmModel 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Hours { get; set; }
    public int Minutes { get; set; }
    public bool Mo { get; set; }
    public bool Tu { get; set; }
    public bool We { get; set; }
    public bool Th { get; set; }
    public bool Fr { get; set; }
    public bool Sa { get; set; }
    public bool Su { get; set; }
}
```

Ну и сам вопрос
Как можно сгруппировать дни недели что-то типа таково

```
public class AlarmModel 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Hours { get; set; }
    public int Minutes { get; set; }
    public DayWeek DayWeek { get; set; }
}

public class DayWeek
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Mo { get; set; }
    public bool Tu { get; set; }
    public bool We { get; set; }
    public bool Th { get; set; }
    public bool Fr { get; set; }
    public bool Sa { get; set; }
    public bool Su { get; set; }
}
```

Сам пробовал получается DayWeek всегда NULL
Это мое первое приложение c Б.Д. поэтому сильно не ругайтесь

Answer (score 2):

> DayWeek всегда NULL

Не инициализированный ссылочный тип всегда null. Вам нужно было бы создать объект класса

```
var alarm = new ALarmModel();
alarm.WeekDays = new();
```

Но то что-вы сделали это создали отдельную сущность связанную 1 к 1 с исходной. Вряд ли это хоть как-то вам помогло.

Если следовать теории нормализации вам надо создать сущность дни недели, а затем связать их с будильниками многие-ко-многим.

Но и это смотрится, как перебор в этом случае.

Вы можете создать флаговый enum и хранить всё так

```
public class AlarmModel 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Hours { get; set; }
    public int Minutes { get; set; }
    public WeekDays WeekDays { get; set; }
}

[Flag]
public Enum DayWeek
{
    None = 0,
    Monday = 1,
    Tuesday = 2,
    Wednesday = 4,
    Thursday = 8,
    Friday = 16,
    Saturday = 32,
    Sunday = 64,
}
```

В общем-то неплохо, если не знать, что в C# уже есть перечисление с днями недели и едва ли вам удобнее работать не с ним. Просто можно взять и положить в список включенные дни.

```
public class AlarmModel 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Hours { get; set; }
    public int Minutes { get; set; }
    public List<DayOfWeek> WeekDays { get; set; }
}
```

Но тут проблема, что списки EF Core не умеет сохранять автоматически (или не умел).

Чтобы он смог нужно в дб-контексте добавлять что-то такое

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder
      .Entity<AlarmModel>()
      .Property(e => e.WeekDays)
      .HasConversion(
          v => string.Join(",", v.Select(e => e.ToString("D")).ToArray()),
          v => v.Split(new[] { ',' })
            .Select(e => Enum.Parse<DayOfWeek>(e))
            .ToList()
      );
}
```

Ну либо 7 версия EF core возможно уже умеет сама это делать, не проверял.

Comment: Спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ !!!